# Better cout a.k.a coutn;

Tags: c++

Guys would it be difficult to write coutn which would basically place newline symbol at the end of the input. While working with console (that's all I can do at the moment) I'm finding very tedious to write '\n' every time I want the line to be a new line.
Or maybe it is already implemented?

Comment: What is so tedious about using `\n` or `endl` when you want a newline to be output?

Comment: Two characters is.... tedious?

Comment: @James The tedious thing is that I have to write it. I do not know how most users but when I have line starting with cout almost 100% of cases this line ends with \n so it would be nice if I didn't have to write it every time. Instead of this I would like to type coutn.

Comment: @Billy two characters every time. That's tedious

Comment: @Knowing me knowing you: Okay then -- Let's ban extra parenthesis in the C++ language. Sure, they can make logic clearer and make things easier to reason, but it's TWO FREAKING EXTRA CHARACTERS EVERY TIME.... :\

Comment: @Billy what extra parenthesis are you talking about? And if you like really extra typing go to Java team. I'm sure you'll be happy there.

Comment: @Billy, @James: Don't you know programmers are the laziest people in the world :-) - That's why the terms "syntactic sugar" not only exist but are also implemented by some syntactic elements as well as dozens or more of API methods, such as, e.g., the "println" methods in Java system.out... BTW, it would also increase readability. I know, its a minor detail, but these details summed up make a difference.

Comment: @chiccodoro: I believe "println" accomplishes the same thing as `std::endl`. More importantly, it doesn't save anything because "ln" is two characters just like "\n" is.

Comment: @Billy: You're right. It accomplishes the same thing as print(somestring + "\n"). Still it exists. Because programmers are lazy, probably, and maybe because readers are lazy too. -- enough said. I think it's best I make a bolt for it now since I'm arguing with c++ programmers. ;-)

Comment: @Knowing me knowing you: The effort you're spending here could have been used to type `<< "\n"` a thousand times. :P

Comment: @Billy it does save another two chars 1 ' and 2 '. Actually SIX in total extra two for << two for ' and ' and two for \n. Does anyone still wanna tell me that this isn't tedious?

Comment: I will:  no, it's not tedious.

Comment: @James well then we have to agree to disagree. I like my code to be as concise as possible while still perfectly readable and understandable.And coutn is a perfect example of this. Instead of extra SIX chars I have to type just one. Even more reader from the very first moment knows that this is line ended with \n character.

Comment: No way to do this while actually reducing the typing required. If you have enough `cout` lines in a single file to actually offset the effort of placing the new class somewhere, including the header and making the necessary calls, your source file is too long.

Comment: @DevSolar You are WRONG. You implementing your class just once and then you can use it in every project.

Comment: @Knowing me knowing you: Yes, but there's no way to invoke that class without using at least as many characters as "\n"

Comment: @Billy could you give an example please because I can't visualise what you're talking about.

Comment: @Knowing me knowing you: Look at the only answer that can accomplish what you want. First, you're putting that into a header file, so you're doing `#include "path/to/header.hpp"`, which is good for 12-14 characters minimum, you've got the extra three characters per invocation "n()", and you send everyone who tries to look at your code on a treasure hunt to find what the hell you're talking about.

Comment: @Billy ONeal First you include header just once and then you can use it in every file you wanted to. And if you type cout quite often then after few times you will actually benefit from it. Second you can #define coutn count() and it looks as good as cout and third after a while when it would be a standard way of doing things you wouldn'g go for treasure hunt just like you do not go every time you see cout.

Comment: Give up. You're on a wolpertinger hunt here. Did you ever stop to realize that everybody except you can live perfectly *without* a `coutn`? Fat chance of that one ever becoming "standard".

Comment: @DevSolar it is not about giving up nor about trying to create a new standard. I just wanted this for myself to make my life easier and thanks to Didier and Matthieu I've got what I wanted for what I'm greatful.

Comment: @DevSolar and if Bill Gates would think that way because someone would tell him that everyone can perfectly live with Dos? Where would we be today? One have to want to make this world better and more perfect. Otherwise we would go tonight to sleep in our caves.

Comment: @Knowing, ultimately the general consensus is that the example is too trivial to warrant so much thought, but I totally agree with your thinking. I read a quote once that said "laziness is a programmer's greatest asset"; Whilst you're thinking "how can i make this easier for myself", you're on the right path. Unlike those that accept "that's just the way it is", possessing your sentiment is the reason we have higher abstractions, meta-programming and the like. Nobody can dispute the significance of these, so whilst the responses you received seemed slightly hostile, I applaud you nevertheless.

Comment: @Jeriko:  Most of the negative comments seemed to me to be that this isn't worth being lazy about, and that the proposed solutions didn't seem to promote the value of laziness, rather than a denigration of laziness.  Larry Wall considers laziness, impatience, and hubris to be the cardinal virtues of programming, but prefers to apply them where they really pay off.  I'm always ready to applaud an elegant demonstration of laziness, but I don't think this is one.  To Knowing me..., keep up the laziness but look for better ways to save time and effort.

Comment: @David: I totally agree.. What I'm saying is that whilst this might not be a suitable situation in practice, he should never stop thinking along these lines :)

Comment: I'm shocked at how much everyone flipped out over this; this isn't a crazy request at all. Java has `PrintStream.println`, Perl 6 has `say`, etc. It's only two characters if you're doing `cout << "foo";`, but it's considerably more if you're doing `cout << var;`; you need to add a whole extra insertion just for the newline

Comment: I have to side with the people saying this isn't an absurd request, however I do feel it would be awkward given C++s stream based interface to IO.  You're also exchanging succinct newlines for succinct flushing.

Comment: On the "nobody will know what you're doing" argument, surely I'm not the only person who has ever worked somewhere with in house utility libraries?  There's going to be a slight learning curve whenever you touch somebody else's code; "automatically adds a newline" is a hell of a lot easier to grok than, say, any given Boost library.

Comment: How on earth was this "closed as not a real question"? The question couldn't be more real. It is not difficult to tell what is being asked. It is not vague. It is not ambiguous. It is not incomplete. It is not rhetorical. It definitely can be answered in it's current form (see @Didier's answer). From what I can see people's objections are that they personally would prefer not to have the newline wrapped up. At which point does that lead to closure? I would use coutn() as I'm used to Qt's qDebug() which appends a newline for me and if I use cout I always forget. I have voted to reopen.

Comment: @Troubadour: I voted to reopen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To circumvent the multiple injections on a single line, you could use a temporary object. This temporary object would add the '\n' in its destructor.

```
struct coutn {
    coutn(): os(cout) {}
    ~coutn() { os << '\n'; }
    template <typename T>
        coutn & operator<<(T const & x) { os << x; return *this; }
private:
    ostream &os;
};

coutn() << "Hello " << "World" << "!";
```

In the end, I'm wondering if this `coutn` is actually *better*?

Comment: +1: Sanity of the desire notwithstanding, this is the best way to fulfill it.

Comment: +1 This was the same idea that I had (except you posted 20 second before me)

Comment: Hmm... seems odd to replace two characters "\n" with three "n()"... (+1 to the answer, the question is inherently asking for something stupid)

Comment: @Billy ONeal what's stupid in wanting to type less than more with the same effect? Really looking forward to your answer.

Comment: @Knowing me knowing you: Because code readability is more important than code length. And this solution has you typing *more*, not less.

Comment: @Billy ONeal what unreadable about coutn? In my opinion it's more readable than cout because you have to check the end of the line to know what it really does and with coutn you do not have to do it. It is just more readable.

Comment: @Knowing: .... stay the hell away from my codebase, and I'll stay the hell away from yours.

Comment: @ Knowing me knowing you - The "unreadable" part of `coutn` is that it looks *almost* like the standard `cout` but isn't, and no-one except you would be using it.

Comment: @Billy, sometimes 2 characters is more than 2 characters. If the last thing you output is a variable, then you have to add `<< '\n'`, for a total of 7 new characters. (More if you want `<< std::endl` instead).

Comment: @Ken: Note that if you want `<< std::endl` instead of a raw new line, you can't use `coutn` as it is implemented here anyhow.  You have to do `coutn() << blah; cout.flush();` which is a net loss no matter how you count things.

Comment: @Dennis. but you could *very* easily modify coutn, and I assume nobody here needs me to tell them that modification was implied.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the first obvious thing would be to implement some kind of wrapper around it:

```
class Print
{
public:
  explicit Print(std::ostream& stream = std::cout): mStream(stream) {}
  ~Print() { mStream << '\n'; }

  template <class T>
  Print& operator<<(T const& t) { mStream << t; return *this; }

private:
  std::ostream& mStream;
};
```

Usage is like such:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Object object;
  Print() << "My new object value: " << object;

  std::ofstream file("file.log");
  Print(file) << "My new object value: " << object;
}
```

Easy, Peasy.

Comment: Yes. Let's replace the tedious two extra characters with a header file, two functions, a template function, a class, and then require more than that two characters whenever anyone wants to use it :\

Comment: Yep, why not?
Anyhow it needs:
#define coutn Print()
to be complete.

Comment: Don't forget the `#define coutn Print()`

Comment: @Billy as I've said in my latest comment two you it's not two chars but four. Becoming more and more tedious don't you think so?

Comment: I don't like the `#define`. The purpose of this object is to be able to choose which stream you output to. As for the name, well if it really matters you can always replace `Print` by `coutn`... but it does not change the design.

Comment: @Billy: The real point, as has been mentioned, is to have this method handles the different platforms as well. `#ifdef` directives should be used to detect the Linux / Windows / Mac world and replace `\n` with the appropriate newline character(s). This is when your `\n` sprinkled everywhere are tedious to replace and where a function shines.

Comment: For any stream opened in text mode (i.e., not binary mode), writing `\n` to the stream causes the platform-specific line ending to be written to the stream, even if the platform-specific line ending is not `\n`.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Why do I have to invent a way to handle the correct newlines when iostreams already provides a perfectly good mechanism for doing so?

Comment: @James McNellis: The wide character specializations often don't handle that correctly.

Comment: @Knowing me knowing you: I don't see how it became 4 characters. Nobody cares how many characters are there. The only thing anyone cares about is how readable your code is. Adding those characters goes a long way toward helping the next person reading your code.

Comment: @Billy first of all in standard way you have to type at least four extra chars (1' 2' 3\ 4n) or SIX (( 1< 2< 3' 4' 5\ 6n). Second thing is that coutn is much more understandable and expressive  to cout because you immediately know looking at coutn that this line  ends with \n. More readable.

Comment: @Billy:  Hmmmmmmm.  Even if you use a wide string literal?  (`L"\n"`)

Comment: @James: Yes, even if you use a wide string literal. (It won't even compile otherwise)

Comment: @Billy: Which platform and how were the streams constructed?

Answer (score 2):

Roughly:

```
struct StreamFilterN
{
   ostream & os;
   StreamFilterN(ostream & os_) : os(os_) {}

    template <typename T>
    StreamFilterN & operator<<(T const & x) { os << x << "\n"; return *this; }
}


StreamFilterN coutn(cout);
coutn << "Hello world";
coutn << "Yeah, like.";
```

(I'm not sure if this works perfectly, but it should get you started)

Comment: We've had the same idea... though there is no `'\n'` anywhere in your answer ?

Comment: +1 Even though there needs to be a os << '\n'; before returning the stream again, it's the solution I find the nicest.

Comment: I'd add `explicit` to the constructor

Comment: @Christian: `coutn << "result: " << r` leads to 2 lines of output. You may find it nice, but it doesn't fulfill the requirements.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: When posting the comment, I didn't know the op wanted the newline to be added only after the last <<. Given the new requirement, you're obviously right ;)

Comment: @Christian: Argh sorry, only saw the new requirements... that's the problem with editing the question/answer: you never know which version the comment are referring to :)

Answer (score 1):

The way that streams work is that they add one thing and then return itself.

so are you sure you'd want to do what you're asking?

For example:

s << "a" << "b";

Would put:

> a
>   b

Surely you can find a way with some kind of wrapper but the extra overhead incurred and the diminished code readability I don't think is worth it.  Most coders are familiar with standard C++.  Most coders are not familiar with your coutn and how it works.

Comment: @Bondy -1 No you are WRONG. You shoud use \n instead of endl. In most cases anyway.

Comment: std::endl and '\n' are two different things. std::endl also flushes the stream which isn't always wanted.

Comment: That's terrible advice. `std::endl` provokes a flush to the output (equivalent to `std::cout.flush()`), which means you lose the benefit of buffering. You only use `std::endl` when you want "instant" feedback, the rest of the time you use `\n` because you only want a newline character.

Comment: Correct.  On some machines an end of line is \r\n.  On some machines it's just \n.  However, std::endl does the right thing every time.

Comment: I find that flushing the stream 'is' what I usually want, especially in the case of cout.

Comment: @Knowing me knowing you and @Yacoby: Using a plain "\n" can cause problems when you are in the Windows environment and are using Unicode, in which case the \n will not get handled perfectly -- you'll often be in cases where you'll need to use "\r\n" instead. Using `std::endl` ensures that you are always using the correct newline character for the given situation. Yes, using `endl` incurs the overhead of flushing the buffer, but for most console applications the bottleneck isn't ever going to be console I/O buffer flushing.

Comment: NO! `cout << '\n'` and `cout << endl` are very different. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245196/c-urban-myths/2245622#2245622

Comment: @Mathieu: output is usually line-buffered anyway.

Comment: @Didier Trosset: They're not the same, yes. However, what makes them different is precisely why you *should* use `std::endl`.

Comment: Guys no one is claiming they are the same. I removed the bit about using std::endl, I just thought endl was what he really wanted to use.  It sounds to me like he wanted to use a newline symbol which would flush the stream.

Comment: It's not necessary to introduce a newline character after each insertion. Think RAII (or look up my answer). I didn't thought about the obnoxious `\r` issue though gah!

Comment: @Bastien: For an application writing large files to disk, I have seen a speedup by a factor of 5-10 when `std::endl` was replaced by `'\n'`.

Comment: @Billy:  So, what you're saying is that VC++ is broken?  `'\n'` is the C++ term for end-of-line in streams not opened in binary format, just as a constant integral zero-valued expression is a C++ term for null pointer constant.

Comment: I absolutely disagree that you *should* use `endl`. You *can* use `endl` if you want to, and if you understand the resulting performance penalty.

Comment: I absolutely disagree that you should use `endl` because of Windows `\r\n` line terminations. Changing the `\n` into `\r\n` is done at a lower level than the injection operators. This conversion (from `\r\n` to `\n` on input, and from `\n` to `\r\n` on output streams) is disabled on Windows when you open the stream using the `std::ios_base::openmode` flag `binary` (that is equivalent to C mode "b" of `fopen()`).

Comment: @ Didier: You might want to note that we are talking about cout here - standard output, which is by default the terminal. Which is line-buffered.

Comment: @DevSolar:  standard output is not necessarily the terminal.  On Unix and Unix-like systems, it's also the input into a pipe to go to the next program, and it's often redirected.

Comment: @ David Thornley: From the C standard: "the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device." So even if you pipe your standard output, it's up to the environment / shell implementation if the pipe / redirection can be *determined* by the C library.

Answer (score 1):

Come one people.  You must admit that C++'s newlines are too verbose.  Look at C#, D, Java, Python, Ruby, should I go on?  I don't think you should implement a `coutn`.  I think you'd be better off following [D's example](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_stdio.html#write) with `write`, `writeln`, `writef`, and `writefln` variadic template functions.

Anyway here is how to do it without macros and with out needing to explicitly create temporaries.

```
class coutn_t
{
private:
   class newliner
   {
   public:
      explicit newliner(std::ostream & out=std::cout) : m_out(out) { }

      template<typename T>
      newliner& operator<<( const T& t)
      {
         m_out << t;
         return *this;
      }
      ~newliner() { m_out << std::endl; }
   private:
      std::ostream & m_out;
   };
public:
   // NOTE: these return by value.  Only one newliner will be
   // destructed however as RVO will eliminate the copy.

   newliner operator()( std::ostream& out )
   { return newliner(out); }

   template< typename T >
   newliner operator<<( const T& t )
   {
      std::cout << t;
      return newliner(std::cout);
   }
};

coutn_t coutn;

coutn << "Hello World!";

coutn << "Hello " << "World" << '!';

std::ofstream file("ouput.txt");
coutn(file) << "Hello World" << " via file";
```

The complete solution will have to add more overloads for `operator<<` to handle stream manipulators (`std::hex` etc).  The functions returning `newliners` must always be inline to allow [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).